# Creating a git alias to append to .gitignore

Tags: git, bash, msysgit

I'm using git 1.9.0 on Windows (msysgit) and I have the following alias:

```
ignore = "!f() { echo $1 >> \"${GIT_PREFIX}.gitignore\"; }; f"
```

And I use it like so:

```
$ git ignore /Directory/Subdir/
```

This should append to my `.gitignore` file within the current directory, or create it if it doesn't exist. However for some reason the path I'm passing in is being converted to an absolute path and I'm not sure why:

Here is what is being appended to my `.gitignore`:

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/Docs/Doxygen/html/
```

Any reason why this is happening?

### EDIT

If I just use the command like so:

```
$ git ignore Docs/Doxygen/html
```

It will not convert the path. So it looks like the forward-slash at the beginning is causing some problems in the shell before the parameter is passed to the alias. Encasing it in quotes doesn't fix it either. I'm at a loss!

### EDIT #2

Tried this:

```
$ git ignore \/Docs/Doxygen/html/
C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/Docs/Doxygen/html/
```

Backslash prior to the forward slash does not fix it either.

### EDIT #3

It's a bug in msysgit I think. I did the same thing in cygwin and look what happens:

```
$ git ignore /Docs/Doxygen/html/
/Docs/Doxygen/html/
```

:-(

Comment: What happens when you pass the path as a string? Like `git ignore '/Docs/Doxygen/html'`?

Comment: I think with MSYS you need to use dual forward slash //Docs/Doxygen/html

Comment: don't you need to use `>` instead of `>>` in order to *append* and not *overwrite*?

Comment: @jimbrig You have it backwards. `>>` appends and `>` overwrites

Comment: Lol must've been tired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conversion rules for msys are documented on the [POSIX path conversion](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Posix_path_conversion) page.

> An argument with a leading / is converted up to the first /

According to the documentation you should prefix your path with // to have only the first slash undergo the conversion, and convert forward slashes to backslashes:

```
//foo\bar ➜ /foo/bar ➜ \ converted to /
```

Try,

```
$ git ignore "//Directory\Subdir\"
```

And,

```
$ git ignore //Directory\\Subdir\\
```

Comment: It is indeed a problem in handling posix paths in arguments in msysgit utilities.

Comment: Thanks this works, although anytime a backslash it used it needs to be escaped like so: `//foo\\bar`. However while this isn't a defect it's a crappy feature because cygwin works just fine for example. The unnecessary backslashes and double forward slashes are incredibly confusing. I may just make cygwin work with git instead of using msysgit directly for this reason.

Comment: @RobertDailey Thanks for the elaboration Robert. I've updated the answer.